# Python - Categorical variable bar chart with percentages

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I'm trying to produce a bar chart to show the percentage of "Male","Female", and "different identity". So, I would like to have Male, Female, and Different Identity appear on the x axis and the percentage on the y axis.

This is my current code which I sourced from somewhere else

sns.barplot(x=ds.Gender, y=x, data = ds, estimator=lambda x: len(x) / len(ds) *100)

Currently, I get the output

**"Neither the `x` nor `y` variable appears to be numeric."**

I've tried to make the 'y' variable something numeric, but I have failed to do so. I've looked at countless other questions but couldn't implement them.

Any help would be much appreciated.

[example of data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtNfL.jpg)

Comment: Can you show a couple of example rows of your dataframe?

Comment: I've since added a print screen of a portion of the data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already giving the `barplot` function the dataframe, so your `x` and `y` arguments can be strings matching columns in your frame. You're correct that the `barplot` will yield percentage on the y-axis with that estimator, and you can pass any numerical column as a dummy to `y`:

```
sns.barplot(x="Gender", y="Age", data=ds, estimator=lambda x: len(x) / len(ds) *100)
```